# Suggested next badge unattainable at current reputation level

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

There seems to be a minor issue with the next badge that is chosen on the user profile. On Meta Stack Overflow I had just gotten the Electorate badge and the next badge the system chose for me was Custodian. The problem with this is that I do not have the necessary reputation in order to earn this badge on that site. Would it be possible to put in a check to preventing it from choosing a badge you don't have the ability to earn?

Comment: You *can* earn it, it might just take a while... step 1: get more rep. ;)

Comment: Or you could manually choose a different one to track.  Though it does seem a little uncouth of the random badge-tracking algorithm to choose one you have to get a new privilege for first.

Comment: @Zibbobz I did chose a different badge to track, but it would be nice to have a badge I can achieve without having to increase my rep by 3.4x what it currently is. :)

Comment: @JoeW It's a motivational tool! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custodian will no longer be suggested/auto-tracked as an onboarding badge on child meta sites, since they only have a subset of very high rep review queues.

This change will go out in the next build, probably in a few hours (but not by me, I'm going to bed :)